# NightmareJs + Jquery return empty JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, nightmare, ruby-paranoia

Im trying to deal with testing tools likewise nightmare, phantom etc. And seems to be stuck with some basic DOM manipulation. Im using jquery here for later use of $().parent() methods. Ive already tryed all posiible selector that come in collection with no use. It only returns some pieces of data. Where it actually fully exists on a page.

```
   ....
nightmare
    .goto(link)
    .inject('js', 'jquery-2.2.4.min.js')
    .wait()
    .evaluate( () => {
        $('.sport--head:not(.folding--open)').click()
    })
    .wait(4000)
    .evaluate( () => {
        let events = [];
        $('.view-wrapper .events--list > li').each( (i, elem) => {
            let event = {
                'name' : $(elem).text()
            }
            events.push(event);
        });
        let data = JSON.stringify(events, null, '\t');
        return data;
    })
    .end()
    ....
```

It returns empty fields where they are actually not:

```
[{ "name": "" }, { "name": "" }, { "name": "" }, { "name": "contents" } ]
```

Why could this happen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not know the pages loads completely within 4 seconds.

Either there are some Ajax data and while you are scraping it appears only at that moment. Or, the selector is actually wrong.

Instead of a specific number, use `.wait` to wait for a target selector,

```
.wait(4000)
.wait('.view-wrapper .events--list > li')
```

Also make sure the code actually returns the data by putting it on console.log of your actual browser.